# FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneCrash: [!] Could not retrieve response as fastlane runs in non-interactive mode

Tags: android, xcode, circleci, fastlane

When I'm running build on circle CI I'm getting following error

> Could not retrieve response as fastlane runs in non-interactive mode
> FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneCrash: [!] Could not retrieve response as fastlane runs in non-interactive mode
> bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/xyz/circleci/.rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/fastlane)
> FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneCrash: [!] Could not retrieve response as fastlane runs in non-interactive mode

I updated the fastlane latest version 2.164.0
I'm not sure what is the exact reason and why it's failing from yesterday, please can you help me to find the solution TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolve the issue with app centre due which I'm not able to upload build on app centre, I have just created new API token on app centre and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by ensuring that I navigate to the correct directory during the CI/CD process. This has successfully fixed the problem.